# Adding mean and standard deviation to data frame and plotting a box plot and a dodged bar chart

Tags: r, boxplot

I am trying to calculate the mean and standard deviation of this data set across each column and then plot a box plot.

**output of dput(DF)**

```
    `structure(list(Cell_Type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
    7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Fibroblast", "T cell", 
    "Macrophage", "Tumor", "Islets of Langerhans", "Endothelial", 
    "B cell"), class = "factor"), Condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("treated", 
    "untreated"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(6051L, 1892L, 1133L, 
    657L, 116L, 868L, 832L, 5331L, 3757L, 1802L, 835L, 287L, 704L, 
    256L), Percent = c(52.3941466793662, 16.3823707680319, 9.8103731924842, 
    5.68880422547407, 1.00441596675037, 7.51580223395965, 7.20408693393367, 
    41.0962072155412, 28.9623805118717, 13.8914585260561, 6.43694110391613, 
    2.21245760098674, 5.42707369719396, 1.97348134443417)), class = c("grouped_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), groups = structure(list(
        Condition = structure(1:2, .Label = c("treated", "untreated"
        ), class = "factor"), .rows = list(1:7, 8:14)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))`

df <- structure(c(6051L, 1892L, 1133L, 893L, 148L, 868L, 5331L, 3757L, 
            1802L, 1061L, 2786L, 704L), .Dim = c(6L, 2L), .Dimnames = structure(list(c("Fibroblast", "T cell", "Macrophage", "Stellate", "Acinar", "Endothelial"), c("treated", "untreated")), .Names = c("", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                          "")), class = "table")
df <- data.frame(df)
```

Which gives the following dataframe:

```
          Var1      Var2 Freq
1   Fibroblast   treated 6051
2       T cell   treated 1892
3   Macrophage   treated 1133
4     Stellate   treated  893
5       Acinar   treated  148
6  Endothelial   treated  868
7   Fibroblast untreated 5331
8       T cell untreated 3757
9   Macrophage untreated 1802
10    Stellate untreated 1061
11      Acinar untreated 2786
12 Endothelial untreated  704

library(dplyr)
DF <- df %>% rename(Cell_Type = Var1, Condition = Var2) %>%
  group_by(Condition) %>% 
  mutate(Percent = Freq / sum(Freq)*100)

# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Condition [2]
   Cell_Type   Condition  Freq Percent
   <fct>       <fct>     <int>   <dbl>
 1 Fibroblast  treated    6051   55.1 
 2 T cell      treated    1892   17.2 
 3 Macrophage  treated    1133   10.3 
 4 Stellate    treated     893    8.13
 5 Acinar      treated     148    1.35
 6 Endothelial treated     868    7.90
 7 Fibroblast  untreated  5331   34.5 
 8 T cell      untreated  3757   24.3 
 9 Macrophage  untreated  1802   11.7 
10 Stellate    untreated  1061    6.87
11 Acinar      untreated  2786   18.0 
12 Endothelial untreated   704    4.56

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Condition, y = Percent, fill = Cell_Type))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(round(Percent,2),"%")), position = position_stack(vjust =  0.5))
```

I have generated a stacked bargraph, but now want to generated a dodge bar chart to show error bars.  How do I go about generating a box plot? The dodged bar chart showing error bars?

Comment: Welcome Michelle to SO. What did you try?Some piece of code?

Comment: Hi @Artur_Indio, I have uploaded what I've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

First, please post questions specifically. I assume you want to know how to perform a means and then sd calculation as per column in your dataset.

First, create a dataframe:

```
df<-structure(list(Cell_Type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Fibroblast", "T cell", 
"Macrophage", "Tumor", "Islets of Langerhans", "Endothelial", 
"B cell"), class = "factor"), Condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("treated", 
"untreated"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(6051L, 1892L, 1133L, 
657L, 116L, 868L, 832L, 5331L, 3757L, 1802L, 835L, 287L, 704L, 
256L), Percent = c(52.3941466793662, 16.3823707680319, 9.8103731924842, 
5.68880422547407, 1.00441596675037, 7.51580223395965, 7.20408693393367, 
41.0962072155412, 28.9623805118717, 13.8914585260561, 6.43694110391613, 
2.21245760098674, 5.42707369719396, 1.97348134443417)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), groups = structure(list(
    Condition = structure(1:2, .Label = c("treated", "untreated"
    ), class = "factor"), .rows = list(1:7, 8:14)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Then, your aim is to analyse your dataset column by column. There are several ways to do this. In base R, you can calculate means and standard deviations manually:

```
mean(df$Freq); mean(df$Percent)
sd(df$Freq); sd(df$Percent)
```

Or, nicely done all together in a package such as *psych*:
    require(psych)
    describe(df)

Last, to plot a box plot, simply use the box.plot prompt for the two numerical variables you have. One by one:

```
boxplot(df$Freq)
boxplot(df$Percent)
```

Or both variables in same plot (but this does not make any sense since Percent is so small in comparison):

```
boxplot(df[,-1:-2])
```

And then you can add headers, legends, colours, etc using typical base R language, e.g.:

```
boxplot(df[,-1:-2], col=c("red", "blue"), main="Box plot of frequencies and percentages", names=c("Frequencies", "Percentages"))
```

Good luck. And please post your question as a question in the future!

Comment: I get this error: `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large` Also, how is the sd being taken into consideration, as I am only calculating it manually and not necessarily adding it to the dataset?